# Start workflow manual but don't show intitation form

Tags: workflow

I want to start a workflow manually, but not to show the initiation form.  (It would use default values).

Is there an easy way to do this?  I couldn't find an option for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with some jQuery and [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Workflow&referringTitle=%24%28%29.SPServices).  This is a script I have on a page with a DVWP.  One of the fields in that DVWP triggers this script on click, starting the workflow.  It's all dynamic except for hard coding the workflow name into the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function StartWorkflow(ItemURL, ItemID) {
var workflowGUID = null;
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetTemplatesForItem",
  item: ItemURL,
  async: false,
  completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("WorkflowTemplates > WorkflowTemplate").each(function(i,e) {
      // hard coded workflow name
      if ( $(this).attr("Name") == "Remove No Show Attendee" ) {              
        var guid = $(this).find("WorkflowTemplateIdSet").attr("TemplateId");        
        if ( guid != null ) {
          workflowGUID = "{" + guid + "}";
          }
        }
      });
  }
});


var workflowTD = '#WorkflowTD' + ItemID;
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "StartWorkflow",
    item: ItemURL,
    templateId: workflowGUID,
    workflowParameters: "<root />",
    completefunc: function() {
      $(workflowTD).html("User Removed");
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

[Here's](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/282282) a helpful discussion we had on it with some other useful links.

Comment: Was really hoping there was just a 'checkbox' for "automatically use default values and don't show intiation form", this does seem like it should work though

Comment: I haven't come across anything like that.  In your case, you should be able to modify the workflowparameters to include your intiation form options.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the initiation form in SP Designer and invoke "click" on "Start" button. You can also hide the buttons for “cleaner” user experience.

```
function getControlByText(el, tagName, txtContains) {
    var ctr = null;
    var elms = el.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    for (var i=elms.length-1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        if (elms[i].innerHTML.indexOf(txtContains) > -1) { 
            ctr = elms[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return ctr;
}

var refWorkflowForm = document.getElementById("WebPartWPQ3");
var refCtlTd = getControlByText(refWorkflowForm, "td", "btnSave");
var refCtlTr;
var refBntStart;
if(refCtlTd) {
    if(refCtlTd.parentNode) { refCtlTr = refCtlTd.parentNode; }
    if(refCtlTd.childNodes[0]) { refBntStart = refCtlTd.childNodes[0]; }
} 

if(refBntStart) {
    refBntStart.click();
    refCtlTr.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: where did you put this script?  I'm trying to supress from a Custom Action, on an Edit Form Ribbon. When I press the button it sends user to an InfoPath form, which I can't insert any kind of code.